# For which values of $x$, following series is converging?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to solve following problem.

Let $x \neq \frac{1}{2}$. Find for which values of $x$, following series is converging:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(\frac{x}{2x-1}\right)^{n} + x^{n}\right).$$

I tied to find when one of the element is dominant, and also when they are smaller than $1$:

$$\left|x \right| \leqslant  \left|\frac{x}{2x-1} \right| < 1$$
or
$$ \left|\frac{x}{2x-1} \right|\leqslant  \left|x \right| < 1.$$

But the solution I'm getting is $0\leq x< \frac{1}{3}$, instead of $-1\leq x< \frac{1}{3}$.

So I know I made a mistake but I can't find it.

Comment: How is the sum convergent for $x = -1$?

Comment: This sum is not converging for x, or I did not understood you right?

Comment: I believe you've solved your absolute value inequality wrong. $\left|x \right| \leqslant  \left|\frac{x}{2x-1} \right| < 1$ gives $0 \leq x < 1/3$. $ \left|\frac{x}{2x-1} \right|\leqslant  \left|x \right| < 1$ gives $-1 < x \leq 0$. Uniting solution one can obtain $-1 < x < 1/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look separately at each term, you conclude that if both $|x|$ and $\left|\frac{x}{2x+1}\right|$ are less than 1, the series will converge, regardless of which one is dominant. So, convergence is assured at least for $-\frac 13 < x <1$.